# Applying point displacement for diagrams in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, overlapping-features, visualisation, diagram

In QGIS 3 I have a point layer with a lot of overlapping and I made diagrams for each point. I would like to displace them as the grid, just like the usual point displacement renderer.

Do you think it is possible? If so how? I couldn't find any answers in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there's no way of doing this natively in QGIS - your best bet is either to find a way of reproducing the diagrams functionality you need with the point renderer so that you can then use point displacement, or displacing the points in the actual data table (such as by using Toolbox > Vector Geometry > Point Displacement).

Answer (score 0):

What you can always do (if you want to displace the points only for visualization, not creating actual geometries) is using the geometry generator with expressions to displace the points (or the diagrams? - it's not clear from your question what you want to displace) based e.g. by some values in the attributes or other criteria. How to do it and how easy (or if at all, with a reasonable effort) that can be done depends on your data. Unfortunately, the information you provided is very scarce, so there's no way to help you but to point to the possibility of using geometry generator.